# Is there a way to calculate a parameter to a command before invoking it?

Tags: mvvmcross

When I bind a button to a command, there doesn't seem to be a way to pass a parameter to the command in the view model.  I know that MvxCommands can have an optional parameter, but how do I pass it one?  Is there some kind of CommandParameter binding option like there is for ConverterParameter?  What would really be nice is if the CommandParameter could be a function that dynamically calculates the parameter to pass to the command.

Comment: duplicate question. please check this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492742/mvvmcross-bind-command-with-parameter-in-c-sharp-code