# Bind command with parameters

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

In my Xamarin iOS project, I want to bind a button to a ICommand with a parameter.

**View:**

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();
set.Bind(Button1).To(vm => vm.EditCommand).WithConversion(new MvxCommandParameterValueConverter(), 1);
set.Apply();
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private readonly ICommand editCommand;
public MyViewModel()
{
   editCommand = new BaseMvxCommand<int>(DoEditPhoto);
}

public ICommand EditCommand { get { return editCommand; } }
private void DoEditPhoto(int imageNum)
{
    // enter code here
}
```

When I hit the button, I am not able to execute the `DoEditPhoto()`. Am I binding in a wrong way? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MvvMCross bind command with parameter (in C# code)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492742/mvvmcross-bind-command-with-parameter-in-c-sharp-code)

Comment: What is BaseMvxCommand?

Comment: BaseMvxCommnad is MvxCommand class. This question is not duplicate to that question as the answers for that question suggested to use command parameters which I am already using but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your binding is technically not wrong. However, you don't need a *converter* to pass a parameter to a bound `ICommand`. For this you can use `CommandParameter` in your chain instead:

```
set.Bind(Button1).To(vm => vm.EditCommand).CommandParameter(ViewModel.ImageNumber);
```

Comment: Works fine here. Your BaseMvxCommand must be doing something wrong.